# ¿como poner mas de una consulta (querys) en un ireport?

Tags: java, ireport

hola a todos tengo un problema nose como insertar un query mas, en mi ireport caundo trato de ingresar un query de esta forma 
`<queryString>............</queryString>`
me sale error, recalco que ya tengo una query que si funciona pero cuando quiero insertar una mas es donde me sale error creo que lo estoy haciendo mal espero su ayuda gracias

les dejo el codigo que funciona, donde tengo q poner el nuevo query o como puedo poner mas de un query gracias

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" columnCount="2" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="420" columnSpacing="2" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\Pits02\\PitsErp\\src\\m_rpt_imp_img\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="id_usuario" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="id_ip" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT ruta_img,serie,orden,correlativo from tab_temp_impresion_img WHERE usuario=$P{id_usuario} and ip_pc=$P{id_ip}]]>
</queryString>
<field name="ruta_img" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="serie" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="orden" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="correlativo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
    <band/>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="198">
        <image scaleImage="RealSize" isLazy="true">
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="9" y="14" width="410" height="182"/>
            <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ruta_img}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="9" y="14" width="298" height="13"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{serie}+'-'+$F{orden}+'-'+$F{correlativo}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes poner más de un datasource en cada report. Si necesitas otra consulta tendrás que crear un subreport y añadirle ahí su consulta.